# Redis move item from middle of list to top

Tags: redis

I was wondering if something like this is possible. I am working with a redis list, and was wondering if I could move a item from the middle of a list to the top of a list like this:

```
LPUSH mylist "This"
LPUSH mylist "is"
LPUSH mylist "a"
LPUSH mylist "Test"

Somehow Move "a" to top

LRANGE mylist
    1. "a"
    2. "This"
    3. "Is"
    4."Test"
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis Lists are implemented using [Linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), and Linked Lists are not suitable for such use (ie. random access and efficient indexing).

You would have to store all the elements until "a" (inclusive) somewhere, then remove them from the list using `LTRIM` and then push them again in the order you want (ie. after `RPOP`ing the last element and `LPUSH`ing it). You could do this using an embedded Lua script since Redis [supports](http://redis.io/commands/eval) this out of the box.

However, if you want each word to appear only once in your list, you could do this efficiently using a [Sorted Set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set). You would have to just update the score of the specific element to something greater than all the others (`ZADD`). Then you'd do a `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to retrieve the re-ordered set.

However, using a sorted set has its trade-offs, mostly that insertion/deletion of elements is slower (ie. happens in logarithmic time) than pushing/poping values from a list (ie. happens in constant time). It all depends in your problem, you should weigh the different approaches (Redis documentation provides the time complexity of each operation) and pick the one that fits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a lua script that will move an item forwards or backwards in a list:

https://github.com/stereosteve/redis-moveby

As the readme indicates, a sorted set may be a better option, and I have not used this in production, so use with care.